# two result rows from two tables with inner join into one row MySQL

Tags: mysql

The records in the table (ucuslar) are as follows.

```
|Id     |tarih |saat |kapasite|
| ----  | ----- | ----- |----- |
|7      |2021-02-15|06:20|23  |
|8    |2021-02-10|07:20|13  |
|33 |2021-02-01|08:20|28  |
|34 |2021-02-05|06:20|18  |
```

The records in the table (ucucular) are as follows.

| Id | durum | ucus_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | net | 8 |
| 189 | ops | 8 |
| 190 | net | 7 |
| 380 | net | 34 |
| 381 | net | 33 |

i have this query and is working.

```
SELECT count(ucus_id) as adet ,durum,kapasite FROM ucucular INNER JOIN ucuslar ON ucuslar.Id=ucucular.ucus_id WHERE ucus_id = 8 group by durum ;
```

| adet | durum | kapasite |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | net | 13 |
| 1 | ops | 13 |

I want the query result to be listed in one line instead of two.

as like this

| net | ops | kapasite |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 13 |

is it possible? Thank you for your interest in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert data (field values) to metadata (field names) seamlessly like that. You're gonna have to write it statically:

```
SELECT
    SUM((uc.durum = 'net')) AS net,
    SUM((uc.durum = 'ops')) AS ops,
    -- ...
    us.kapasite
FROM ucucular uc
INNER JOIN ucuslar us ON us.Id=uc.ucus_id
WHERE uc.ucus_id = 8
;
```

or use prepared statements.

This is denormalization, and in my experience usually worthless to accomplish on the database side.